# How to double encodeURIComponent in javascript?

Tags: javascript, url, character-encoding

In my web app, I use a mailto link to open the outlook 2007. I also insert a url into the body. The problem is I need the whole url to be a hyperlink. If there is any spaces, then the hyperlink breaks, or even if there is any special characters like if it ends with a close parenthesizes the character wont be included in the hyperlink, so the link breaks.

What I tried was using `encodeURIComponent` on the link, which url encodes it, but the issue is that in outlook, it will automatically decode it back to normal which then breaks the link. What I need is a way to double encode it.

Basically instead of doing

`" "` -> `"%20"`  (<-- `encodeURIComponent`)

I need

`" "` -> `"%2520"`

So that in outlook, the `%25` gets decoded to `%`, which when combines with the `20` so I get `%20` keeping the link encoded once and not broken. This is what would work for me, but I just don't know how to do this function.

Does anyone know how I can do this double encode?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Encode

```
var encoded=escape(encodeURIComponent(' '));
```

Decode

```
 var decoded=decodeURIComponent(unescape(encoded));
```

Comment: When I tried this, it didn't encode the `)` in the end, and it was left as normal text and not part of the hyperlink.

Comment: Seems like `escape` is deprecated will `encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(value))` workl.?

Comment: @JohnsonCherian `encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(value))` didn't work for me.