# Gmail App Stripping Out Equals Sign in Mailto Body

Tags: php, android, html, gmail

I am attempting to create a mailto link which populates the body of the email with the current URL.
The problem I am having, is that the gmail android app strips out equals signs, including %3D

Here is the code I am using.

```
$currentUrl = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
$currentUrl = str_replace('&', '%26', $currentUrl);
$currentUrl = str_replace('=', '%3D', $currentUrl);

<a href='mailto:?subject=".$emailsubject."&body=".$currentUrl."' class='actions'>Click to Send</a>
```

Example Href

```
<a href='mailto:?subject=12/12/2019 2L36 Brighton to Lewes&body=https://live.rail-record.co.uk/train/?c%3DW26711%26d%3D12/12/2019' class='actions'>Create Email</a>
```

On desktop, it works fine. On mobile, the query strings get cut off and the equals signs do not get included in the email body.

Would anyone be able to assist please, as to how to get the equals into gmail app? Thanks.

An example of the mailto body would contain a link like this: https://live.rail-record.co.uk/train/?c=H17216&d=11/12/2019
The URL inserted into the email body however, is cut off after ?c - the first equals sign. Works fine in desktop mail apps but doesnt work on gmail android. Regarding the above link, there is a bit at the bottom that says "Create Email" you can click that to test it.

Comment: Maybe you have to encode the '?' too?

Comment: No luck with encoding the ? unfortunately, just tried using %3F and made no difference, for the equals is still missing.

Comment: Try to replace &,=,? with &amp;, &#61;,&#63;.

Comment: No luck either unfortunately. Gets stripped out by gmail as well

Comment: There should be no spaces in the subject too. Replace with %20.

Comment: Thanks, replaced spaces with %20 although unfortunately not solved the issue with the equals. Ive sent a bug report to gmail anyway as it works fine on other apps.

Comment: I have the same problem. As soon as you enter an equal sign (encoded or not), the body of the mailto stops right there. Works on PC, Apple, GMail Desktop, Amazon Fire but fails in Android Gmail.

Comment: any luck with this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: No luck yet unfortunately. Would consider a bounty but it appears to be a gmail app issue at this moment in time.

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue. Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: No solution has been found yet. Still awaiting answers

Answer (score 2):

In Android URL encoding is not enough, you need to double encode the URL and it will work fine (tied it out myself).

Here you can see how to do it in js:
[How to double encodeURIComponent in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407078/how-to-double-encodeuricomponent-in-javascript)